# C# LINQ Most Efficient Way to Sort Dates DESC with NULL First

Tags: c#, linq, coding-efficiency

I have a dataset containing a nullable datetime field.  I want to sort that field descending but with NULL values first.

This code works and returns exactly what I want:

```
var groupedResult = fullResults.OrderBy(c => c.ClientName).ThenBy(t => t.ContactName).ThenByDescending(d => d.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue);
```

I'm new to LINQ so what I'm wondering is if there is a more efficient or preferred way of achieving this same result.

Comment: Is this an in-memory collection, or a database? If the latter, which technology (EF, Linq2SQL, ...)? Comparisons with null have different meanings in databases and memory

Comment: The dataset is originating in SQL Server - it is returned from a stored procedure.  But at this point in the code it is in memory.  Both groupedResult and fullResults are IEnumerable<T> using a custom class.

Comment: I don't see something that would bother me, may I ask what your issue with your written code is?

Comment: No issue - I'm just new to LINQ and wondering if I'm missing anything.  If there's a better way to handle this I'd like to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, likely not.  LINQ will put all of the order clauses together and run them as efficiently as possible for you.  It will be up to the engine to figure out how to do it efficiently (SQL/In-Memory/etc.).